# How to perform onClick event in alertDialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

i created one exception class, inside declared Alert Dialog with OK button. Now i use this dialog in another class, this time when i click OK button it will redirect to another activity.

```
public class ExceptionClass {
public static void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();        
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);        
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);         
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });       
    alertDialog.show();
}}
```

Now i used this dialog in another class,like this

```
 ExceptionClass.showAlertDialog(Activity2.class, "Title","error message" , true);
```

Now when i click OK button then it will redirect to Activity1.

Comment: Simply start the `Activity1` from inside the `onClick()` method.

Comment: actually this alert dialog i used in many activities,so whatever activity i used that time i nedd click ok button, then it will redirect to the target activity. Just for understanding i put two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a intent with the activity which you want to launch and change your showAlertDialog() method by adding one more parameter with the created intent.

```
showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status, Intent activityToBeLaunch)
```

And on "OK" button click start activity with the passed intent.

```
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           context.startActivity(activityToBeLaunch);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the activity reference as a parameter to "showAlertDialog" method.And just launch that activity.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call your AlertDialog from anotherclass. Create another one inside that class if you need. Then each of your AlertDialogs can perform different actions.

```
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    //start your activity here
    Intent i = ne Intent(ExceptionClass.this,Activity1.class); 
    startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onClick` of `OK` you need to create intent and start activity.

write bellow one line code. It will work

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Activity1.class));
```

Answer (score -1):

The method named `showAlertDialog` is `static`. You want to call the method in any activity? You can make callback method inside onclick.